# Can i set a footer to an empty listview in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

What i want to know?
I was little curious about if i can add a footer to an empty ListView in android. I checked the documentation of ListView footer but they haven't mentioned anything related to this. So just wanted to know if it is possible?

Why i need this?
Actually i have edittext(search box) in my application which will accept characters as input from user. On the basis of this entered text i will do some search in DB & display the matching results in the ListView. What i am planning to do is to display a button at the bottom of ListView(something like footer) which will provide a extended search option to user.

Some code for reference :

```
    @Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
{
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
{
    strGuestCardToSerach = s.toString();

    if(strGuestCardToSerach.equals(""))
    {
        if(listview.getFooterViewsCount() > 0)
        {
            listview.removeFooterView(footerView);
            listviewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(listview.getFooterViewsCount() == 0)
        {
            footerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer_view_layout, null);
            listview.addFooterView(footerView);
            listview.setAdapter(recentGuestAdapter);
            listviewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
{
}
```

@Edit :
It does work once you have at least one entry in the ListView. So just wanted to understand if at all it is possible to add a Footer to an empty ListView.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried anything

Comment: Yes, I tried a typical way suggested in many posts on the SO, Added a footer to the listview & then set adapter to it. But it doesn't seems to work in case of empty listview.

Comment: post the code what are you doing... i suggest you in the case when your listview is empty just add your view as header and when there is a content add it as footer.

Comment: @Android-Developer : It's a part of complex system & has proprietary licensing issue as well. So can't post the entire code but this is the code snippet where i am doing my related entire stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am posting this just in case if anyone is looking for the similar functionality as mine. Answer is NO, you can't add a footer view to an empty ListView. To achieve the similar functionality you will have create your own layout & add it explicitly to the ListView & manage it's state.

Rupesh

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you use a ListAdapter on your ListView? Just add a "footer item" to your ArrayList/ whatever of list items. In the getView method, check if the item is your footer, then set a custom layout on it where you have your buttons or whatever. Just ask if it's not clear what I mean.

Comment: Disregard that, I misunderstood your question I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but what you have suggested is more like an workaround i believe. Can't this be done by using setFooterView method of android framework. Thanks for the suggestion though. :)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this scenario when list is empty:
Create to adapter and assign them layouts:

1. when list is not empty assign adapter to it with layouts.
2. when list is empty assign list a dummy adapter and with one initial value.
3. donot assign value to dummy layout in getview or give size to dummy view to 0 dp.
   so you can achieve this scenario...
   ask further i have solve this scenario

Answer (score 0):

```
public void addFooterView (View v)
Added in API level 1
Add a fixed view to appear at the bottom of the list. If addFooterView is called more than once, the views will appear in the order they were added. Views added using this call can take focus if they want.
Note: When first introduced, this method could only be called before setting the adapter with setAdapter(ListAdapter). Starting with KITKAT, this method may be called at any time. If the ListView's adapter does not extend HeaderViewListAdapter, it will be wrapped with a supporting instance of WrapperListAdapter.
Parameters
v
The view to add.
```

Comment: I had done the same in my original implementation, as mentioned in my question.