# ListView footer displays even before the list is loaded

Tags: android, listview

I have a list of items that are loaded from the web. There is an animation that runs while the list data is loaded in the background. I have a requirement of adding the footer view to the listview. This works well, expect that the footer view is visible even before the list is loaded. I have tried several things to circumvent this. But it just does not happen. I have attached the code along with a question. Please see if you can help me out. [image]Thanks :)

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        load = new Button(this);
        // load.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // load.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        // LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        load.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dialogbutton));
        load.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffffff"));
        listView.addFooterView(load);

        load.setText("Show more Offers");

        load.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                loadingLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                loadigIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                loadingViewAnim.start();
                int start = end;
                end = end + 10;

                String urll = "http://www.squeakee.com/api/androidAPI/API.classSearchN.php?&lat=19.175655922901&long=72.83366315066814&sct=Mumbai&redius=6.4209294&type=view&catid=&srch=&spr=APP&mth=list";
                Log.d(TAG, "start=>" + start);
                url = urll + "&start=" + start + "&end=" + end;
                JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(url.replace(
                        " ", "+"), null, new JSONRequest(), new JSONError());
                request.setShouldCache(false);
                requestQueue.add(request);

            }
        });
        mLaderInsideButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.refreshButton1);
        frameAnimation2 = (AnimationDrawable) mLaderInsideButton.getDrawable();
        // layoutShowMore = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ln_showmore);

        loadingLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);
        loadingLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        loadigIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView111);
        loadigIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        loadigIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.loading_animation1);
        loadingViewAnim = (AnimationDrawable) loadigIcon.getBackground();

        LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        footerView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_footer_view, null);
        entities = new ArrayList<OfferEntity>();
        url = getIntent().getExtras()
                .getString(SqueakeeMapListViewPager.APPTAG);
        url = url + "&start=" + INITAIL_START + "&end=" + ININTIAL_END;

        Log.d(TAG, "url=>" + url);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        requestQueue = RequestQueueHolder.getQueue(this);
        mLaderInsideButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        frameAnimation2.start();

        // use to parse jsonobjects
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(
                url.replace(" ", "+"), null, new JSONRequest(), new JSONError());
        request.setShouldCache(false);
        request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(20000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        adapter = new OfferAdapterList(this, entities, false);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        requestQueue.add(request);
```

Comment: try moving this `listView.addFooterView(load);` above `listView.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: It is way above setAdapter, are u saying move it just above setAdapter?

Comment: yes just above setAdapter and read this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView(android.view.View)

Comment: footer is displayed if listview is populated by atleast 1 item. If listview is empty footer will not be displayed

Comment: you can read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293751/can-i-set-a-footer-to-an-empty-listview-in-android

Comment: put that comment as an answer, i will accept it. It did light the bulb in my brain!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListView footer is displayed if there is atleast 1 item displayed in listview.

If the listview is empty the footer is not displayed.

[Can i set a footer to an empty listview in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293751/can-i-set-a-footer-to-an-empty-listview-in-android)

Adding Abby's comment to the answer.

Quoting

The problem was i set the adapter even before the list was loaded and when the list loaded i called notifyDataSetChanged. I tweak the code to set the adapter when the list was loaded first time, n later on it calls notifyDataSetChanged. Works like a charm

Comment: The problem was i set the adapter even before the list was loaded and when the list loaded i called notifyDataSetChanged. I tweak the code to set the adapter  when the list was loaded first time, n later on it calls notifyDataSetChanged. Works like a charm